# BeautifulSoupで不要なタグを削除方法

Tags: python, python3, beautifulsoup

下に記述したHTMLコードの中から『**取得したい文字列**』を取得するには`<LI>・<a>`ですが、
`<LI>・<a>` も`<time>`・`<span>`等があるため、省くことができません。

教えてください。

例:

```html
<li><a href="XXXXXXXXXX">取得したい文字列
<time>tt:mm</time>
<time><ige></time>
<span>1</span>
<div></div>
</a></li>
・
・
・
```

Comment: 閉じタグの多くが`<\ `になっていますが`</`のtypoではありませんか？ それから自分で作成・実行して上手くいかなかったソースコードやその結果と、それの何処が問題なのかについて追記した方が良いでしょう。こちらのヘルプ記事を参考に。[良い質問をするには？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [再現可能な短いサンプルコードの書き方](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: 回答が質問に合わない, なにか齟齬があると思える場合は, 質問をよりよく(誤解が含まないように)[編集](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/posts/92384/edit)してみてください。(回答に対するコメントに数人が書き込むとどれに対するコメントかがわかりにくいので)

Comment: どのような結果を期待しているのか。最終的にどんな内容を取得したいのか, を「期待する結果」として質問に追加すると伝わるかもしれない。現在の質問内容で『取得したい文字列』は回答に示したとおりです

Answer (score 1):

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import sys

html_contents = '''
<li>
  <a href="XXXXXXXXXX">取得したい文字列
    <time>tt:mm</time>
    <time><ige></time>
    <span>1</span>
    <div></div>
  </a>
</li>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_contents, 'html.parser')
elm = soup.select_one('li > a[href]')
if elm is None:
    sys.exit(1)

wanted = elm.contents[0].strip()
print(wanted)

#
# 取得したい文字列
```

Comment: マークアップ言語なので、要素内にはテキストも他の要素も存在します。何を正解としたコードなのか明記してください。

Answer (score 1):

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''
<li><a href="XXXXXXXXXX">取得したい文字列
<time>tt:mm</time>
<time><ige></time>
<span>1</span>
<div></div>
</a></li>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

a = soup.a   # アンカータグ a 要素
strs = [s for s in a.strings]
strs[0]
# 取得したい文字列\n
print(strs[0].strip())
# 取得したい文字列
```

Comment: マークアップ言語なので、要素内にはテキストも他の要素も存在します。何を正解としたコードなのか明記してください。

Comment: 『取得したい文字列』を取得するには, と質問に書いてありますが？

Comment: LI要素内のa要素にはCTEXTが他にも存在しますが、それらをどうするかの記載がないので、仮定をきちんとしてください(そもそも省きたいものの正確な表現がない)。

Comment: すみません。説明不足で。

Comment: 取得したい文字列以外を削除もしくは、非表示の状態にしたいです。

Comment: おおっと、通知なかったのですが質問者さんからコメントがあったんですね。a要素の中には、"取得したい文字列\n    ",time要素, "\n    ", time要素, "\n    ", span要素, "\n    ", div要素 が入っていますよね。またtime要素やspan要素の中、各要素の間にもテキスト(CDATA)(前のコメントだとうっかりCTEXTと書いてた)が入っていたりします。それらの内、何を取得して、何を削除していいのかが厳密ではないのです。質問者さんが記述しきれてないなら、コメントして質問を修正していけばいいのですが、回答者さんがそこを端折って回答すると不正確な回答になってしまいます。仮にやむを得ない事情があって問答を控えたのであれば、質問に対する追加の仮定が必要になるので、それを記述すべきなのですが、なかったので指摘した次第です。